# Illegal Configuration "Frame Size not a member of its required content sizes" iAd setup?

Tags: iphone, iad

I don't see that method in there...  I just put the iAd banner in using xcode at the top of a drill down table tutorial.  I tried it at the top and at the bottom.

It seems to compile and run in the simulator... but I get this error.  I'm trying to add iAds to a table view app.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated?

```
-(void) bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner{
if (!self.bannerIsVisible)
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOn" context:NULL];
    banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, -banner.frame.size.height);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    self.bannerIsVisible = YES;

}}

-(void) bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error {
if (self.bannerIsVisible)
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOff" context:NULL];
    banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, banner.frame.size.height);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    self.bannerIsVisible = NO;

}}
```

Comment: It sounds more an issue with the frame/bounds initialisation. Did you use sizeFromBannerContentSizeIdentifier ? Maybe you can post this piece of code.

Comment: It looks like it works fine if you add a subview... apparently that was the problem.  Sorry... new to this stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exact same issue in Xcode 4.2.1 when trying to add ADBannerView to TableView in a nib. It looks like a bug from Xcode or iAd framework.

This can be walkaround by following steps:

1. Add ADBanner View to TableView.
2. Switch to Attribute Inspector and click the ADBanner view.
3. Change "Orientation" to "Portait" and compile the Project. The error will be gone.
4. You could now change it back to "Both" again, and you won't see the error any more.